# Can renders be made to include glossy reflections, after baking on textures without glossy in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texture-baking

I have a large interior scene with a lot of complex lighting, and I'm trying to reduce render times in it as much as possible. It includes lots of point and area lights, and exterior light filtering between beams. So, I'm looking for a way to bake the diffuse lighting onto the textures of objects, but have the glossy reflections be calculated during rendering. Can that be done?

It has occurred to me that maybe this can be faked, by baking everything except glossy, creating copies of the objects, and under Cycles settings leaving only glossy on for the copies ... Would that then mean that rendering is only calculating those glossy reflections on the fly, and doing everything else with the textures, so it is still a lot faster?

This is the sort of situation I'm dealing with:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Blender 2.79. Under 'Render" (down at the bottom) there is a section marked "Bake". Within this section de-select "Glossy". This is different from your workflow you described, which is to fake it through the Object settings.

[image: Screenshot of Render toolbar and Bake section]

Comment: That looks after the part to do with not including the glossy reflections in the bake, certainly a better way that i had considered. To then get realistic glossy rays in renders, does the faking approach i'm considering work?

Comment: If you then render as per normal, you save a lot of calculations with the baking, but the gloss (which was not baked) should be calculated on the fly. Give it a go, it will only cost you some render time!

Comment: No, the gloss isn't put in if it isn't in the bake. It just gave me the baked item with its surface the way i'd told it it should be, as baked, and put glossy reflections only on other items, as i feared. I'm going to try editing the question. After your input, i understand the question doesn't really explain my issue.